# How do you get the full image url for emails with asset pipeline and Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, asset-pipeline, actionmailer

I am trying to render out HTML for emails that include images with full urls. I am using Rails 3.2 (asset pipeline) and Heroku. I don't know where my problem is.

I added this method to my application helper:

```
def image_url(source)
  "#{root_url[0..-2]}#{image_path(source)}"
end
```

In email.html.erb:

```
<img src="<%= image_url("images/email/logo.gif") %>" width="102" height="40">
```

But the emails result in getting something like:

```
http://assets/email/logo-64cb67810752117f1de94cbb1c57a146.png
```

I assumed this meant that my root_url was blank on Heroku. I have tried setting it in my production.rb file like so:

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { host: "www.domainname.com" }
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

What do I need to do to correctly render images with full urls in emails?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant part of the template as well?

Comment: Added example from email template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'www.domainname.com'
```

Answer (score 1):

In rails4

config/environments folder, you may have three environment specific files, you can put this configuration to set your domain

`config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://www.yourdomain.com'`

Answer (score -1):

Also you can do: `image_url('file.png', host: 'http://example.com')`